# Prev working PS script that checks remote computer services fails when run as a scheduled task but runs when kicked off manually same user creds

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I have a powershell script that has been working fine for years. It started failing around early-mid November. It runs nightly to check and remediate any listed services that are not running. It uses the get-service commandlet.

The script stopped working on multiple platforms when running it as a scheduled task. Script runs fine when running as the same user (creds) as the scheduled task but running from the command line.

Script on the scheduled task doesn't fail, but it doesn't access the remote systems and gather information. The scheduled task status shows it completed successfully. But the results all return an error status from my script that the service state wasn't able to be determined.

All systems have winRM service running.

Scheduled task is set to run with highest permissions, even when the user is logged off.

Typical Response/Results when ran manually:

Testing [1 / 1] server1
[2d] ( server1 : service_a: Running )

[2d] ( server1 : service_b: Running )

[2d] ( server1 : service_c : Running )

When ran as a scheduled tasks:
Sanity check just checks for a well known service after failing to find the services I am specifically looking for.

SanityCheck: ()
server1: Sanity Check failed, Something isn't right with the asset. It's not just an xx service issue

$sanityCheck = Get-Service RpcSs -ComputerName $target

Comment: A schedule task runs by default using a System Account with no environmental variables.  You need to run the task with an account that has environmental variables.  Normal solution is to create a Service Account and run the task using the Service Account.